# How to prevent aoColumnDefs applying to header and footer in DataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

This is a part of my code where I apply class name into table cells.

```
"aoColumnDefs" : [{
    "sClass" : "email",
    "aTargets" : [0]
}]
```

However it applies also into `tfoot` and `thead` `th`s. How I can make it apply only into `tbody` `th`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use standard css syntax to get only the body

```
td.email {color: green;}
```